# How to get struct that is inside the class?

Tags: c++

Let say I have class

```
class A{
public:
    struct stuff{
        int x;  
        int y;
    }; 
    stuff get_stuff(int index){
       if(index < vec_stuff.size() && index >= 0) return vec_stuff[index];
       else return nullptr;
    }
    std::vector<stuff> vec_stuff;
};
```

Assume I populate those `vec_stuff` appropriately.

Then In some other class

```
#inclde "A.h"
class B{
public:
     B(){}

     void f(int index, int k){

        xxxx =  a.get_stuff(index) 
     }

    A a; // assume A is initialized properly
}
```

So in the place where I wrote `xxxx` there it should be `struct stuff` but when I do this I get `use of undeclared identifier` So how do I make compiler know that `stuff` I am referring is inside of A.

Comment: `else return nullptr;` HUH??

Comment: `auto`? -------

Comment: @WhiZTiM Or `auto xxxx = a.get_stuff(index);`. This would have the advantage to work even with `private` nested structs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, true. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either specify the fully qualified name by using the scope-operator:

```
A::stuff xxx = a.get_stuff(index);
```

Or if your compiler supports C++11 or later you can use the `auto` keyword and let the compiler figure out the type:

```
auto xxx = a.get_stuff(index);
```

---

As a side note:

Your `get_stuff` method shouldn't even compile since it's trying to return a `stuff` object, `nullptr` is not a `stuff` object.

```
stuff get_stuff(int index){
   if(index < vec_stuff.size() && index >= 0) return vec_stuff[index];
   else return nullptr;
}
```

If it's expected to have a value and thus it's an exceptional case, then you should throw an exception. Otherwise you can let it return a `stuff*` and just do return `&vec_stuff[index]`.

Comment: regarding `return nullptr` so should I just `throw exception` then?

Comment: @pokche Depends on your use case. If it's expected to have a value, it's an *exceptional* case, then yes you should. Otherwise you can let it return a `stuff*` and just do return `&vec_stuff[index];`

Comment: @GillBates: or an "optional" wrapper. Frankly throwing an exception is a reasonable, simple and clear approach, regardless of mantras

Comment: @GillBates oh! I just read your last line .. now it makes sense.